# Error when building the project after add a <jarModule> to maven pom.xml :Artifact is not a dependency of the project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-ear-plugin

I have added a new `<jarModule>` to my maven `pom.xml` file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    ............
    <jarModule>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <excluded>true</excluded>
    </jarModule>
    ............
</plugin>
```

All the project building was happend correctly until I added this `<jarmodule>`.

An Error will shown like below:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.6:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project ABCD  : Artifact[jar:javax.transaction:jta] is not a dependency of the project.`

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something I've missed? Thanks.

Comment: <modules>
             <webModule>
               <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
               <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
               <excluded>true</excluded>
             </webModule>
          </modules>

Comment: @RaghunandanKrishnamurthy : what is this ??

Comment: usually you add only war's/ejb modules to an ear. Or if you add jar's than you have to add them into the dependencies section before (That's what the error message mentions).

Comment: @khmarbaise :  <excluded>true</excluded> what is meant by this tag ?

Comment: Take a look at the error message `is not a dependency of the project.`.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm you need to add a dependency in your project dependencies section:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>x.y</version>
      <type>jar</jar>
    </dependency>
```

Replace `x.y` by the right version.
Note the `<type>jar</jar>`. I had a similar error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.7:generate-application-xml  
(default-generate-application-xml) on project xxx:  
Artifact[ejb:a.group:anArtifact] is not a dependency of the project.
```

And that even though my dependency was there!
But I was missing `<type>ejb</type>` in said dependency.